# Simple transparent proxy in python - proxying http requests

Tags: python, networking, proxy

My case:

```
App A - should send http/https queries through proxies
```

Problem that app A could not use proxies that have login/password auth. 
So I want to create proxy server that just authorise and send request as it is farther.

I want create second app that provide ports on localhost with proxies. I plan to make simple rest or thrift api for providing and managing proxies. That isn't a problem, the problem is handling the request:

```
App A -> App B (as localhost proxy) -> Proxy with password -> network
```

So what libs should I use to implement this in python?

Just to clarify, question is not about how to use proxy from python, but about hot to make transparent proxy server.

*PS I can use any solution in java or some open source app if it's not possible or too hard in python.*

Comment: how is the auth done? Via HTTP headers?

Comment: This is format of proxies `http://login:password@0.0.0.0:976`

Comment: Have you looked at `HAProxy`?

Comment: @MagdKudama, yeah, but not dive to deep. I need to load proxies from database and dynamically serve proxy. Is it possible with haproxy and can I manage haproxy from python by api?

Comment: No I don't think HaProxy can do that. Maybe there's a plugin, but I don't really know.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send http/https request using a proxy through Python you can use request library. Here is some example:

```
import requests
base_url = 'https://whatever.com'
proxy = {"https":"https://user:pass@proxy_url:port"}

resp = requests.get(base_url, proxies=proxy)
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, but question is about how to make transparent proxy server that proxy raw requests not about how to send request throw proxy

Comment: Then I would recommend to have a look at this https://gist.github.com/darkwave/52842722c0c451807df4